# SparkR : Huge number of files being created on temp folder

Tags: apache-spark

I am Trying to use this sparkR an integration of spark and R . I see there are a huge number of small files being created on the machine.

Any Idea how to fix this

Comment: Give detail on where the files are and what they are named. This clarifies whether they are related to Spark or SparkR.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the input files and how many? Why is the small files a problem?

You can try repartitioning your data into less partitions, I've seen that help, e.g. (in Scala)

```
ss.textFile("path/to/file").repartition(100).yourCode ...
```

Sorry, I don't know about the R API, I stick to Scala I find it's much more powerful and robust - give it a try :)